# Optional secondary indexes in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I am migrating my persistence tier from Riak to DynamoDB. My data model contains an optional business identifier field, which is desired to be able to be queried as an alternative to the key.

It appears that DynamoDB secondary indexes can't be `null` and require a range key, so despite the similar name to Riak's secondary indexes, make this appear quite a different beast.

Is there an elegant way to efficiently query my optional field, short of throwing the data in an external search index?

Comment: From my past experience, a query requires that the primary index is also queried, in addition to the secondary one. Point being that you won't be able to query by the secondary index alone. This might have changed in the meantime, but I doubt it. You can easily run a query to check this.

Comment: Thanks Andrei; that was the conclusion that I came to. I ended up querying my Elasticsearch index for retrieving data by business identifier. It's kinda misusing a search index, but needs must.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you asked this question, DynamoDB did not have Global Secondary Indexes: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/12/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes/

Now, it does.

A local secondary index is best thought of, and functions as, a secondary range key.  @andreimarinescu is right: you still **must** query by the item's hash key, only with a secondary index you can use a limited  subset of a DynamoDB query's comparison operators on that range key (e.g. greater than, equal to, less than, etc.) So, you still need to know which "hash bucket" you're performing the comparison within.

Global secondary indexes are a bit of a different beast.  They are more like a secondary version of your table (and Amazon charges you similarly in terms of provisioned throughput).  You can use non-primary key attributes of your table as primary key attributes of your index in a global secondary index, and query them accordingly.

For example, if your table looks like:

```
|**Hash key**: Item ID | **Range Key**: Serial No | **Attribute**: Business ID |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           1          |        12345             |             1A             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|           2          |        45678             |             2B             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|           3          |        34567             |            (empty)         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           3          |        12345             |             2B             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, with a local secondary index on `Business ID` you could perform queries like, "find all the items with a hash key of `3` and a business ID equal to `2B`", but you could not do "find all items with a business ID equal to `2B`" because the secondary index requires a hash key.

If you were to add a global secondary index using business ID, then you could perform  such queries.  You would essentially be providing an alternate primary key for the table.  You could perform a query like "find all items with a business ID equal to `2B` and get items `2-45678` and `3-12345` as a response.

Sparse indexes work fine with DynamoDB; it's perfectly allowable that not all the items have a business ID and can allow you to keep the provisioned throughput on your index lower than that of the table depending on how many items you anticipate having a business ID.

Comment: so globa secondary index is like making a copy of your table with different hash key. that means your storage usage will increase. for example,if my table is 100mb large using secondary index will make it 200mb used. is it true?

Comment: @batmaci Sort of. What I mean by that is that you will have to pay for additional provisioned throughput on the table for a global secondary index. Note that you do not have to double your provisioned throughput for the table - you can set the main throughput capacities and the index throughput capacities independently of one another. I don't believe it would actually require doubling the actual storage size of the data, but that's an implementation detail that Amazon handles and you don't have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The same is also possible using LSI.
Just make sure that you don't write any data to that Attribute.

In my scenario, for a LSI, I was writing empty string (""), which is not allowed. I skipped initialization of the sort key and it worked fine.

Basically DynamoDB won't even create the that attribute for that row.

Details of behavior is explained below

[How can I make a sparse index if the key is always required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575985/how-can-i-make-a-sparse-index-if-the-key-is-always-required/48633818)