# DynamoDB: range vs. global secondary index

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a user table with `id` and `timestamp` attributes. I would like to be able to query on both parameters. If I understand the documentation correctly, there are two ways of doing this with DynamoDB:

1. Define a hash+range primary key using `id` as the hash and `timestamp` as the range.
2. Define a hash-only primary key using `id` and define a global secondary index using `timestamp`.

What are the benefits and drawbacks of each approach?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Define a hash+range primary key using id as the hash and timestamp as
>   the range.

By making `id` the `Hash Key` and `timestamp` the `Range Key`, you are effectively creating a 'composite primary key'.

In order words, your DynamoDB schema would allow the following data (notice that 'john' is repeated three times)

```
id (Hash) | timestamp (Range)
----------|-------------------------
john      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
john      | 2014-04-28T08:53:29.000Z
john      | 2014-04-28T09:53:29.000Z
mary      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
jane      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
```

And you can perform these operations:

1. `GetItem` to get a single item based on the `id` (Hash Key) + `timestamp` (Range Key) combination
2. `Query` to get a list of all items equal to the `id` (Hash Key)

If this is not what you intended for, then hash + range on `id` and `timestamp` respectively is not what you are looking for.

> Define a hash-only primary key using id and define a global secondary
>   index using timestamp.

Using a hash-only primary key on `id`, `id` must be unique.

```
id (Hash) | timestamp (GSI Hash Key)
----------|-------------------------
john      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
mary      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
jane      | 2014-04-28T07:53:29.000Z
```

Then by applying `GSI` hash-only on `timestamp`, you would be able to query for a list of `ids` for a particular `timestamp`.

The **benefits** to this approach is that, it is definitely the correct solution for your use case. #1 is misuse of range key (unless you are intending to ensure at the application level `id` is not duplicated which is probably a bad idea).

The **drawback** to using `GSI` are:

1. <s>There can only be a maximum of 5 `GSI` per table, so choose wisely what you want indexed</s> **DynamoDB Update Dec 2019** - You can now create as many as 20 `GSI` per table, and can further raise this soft limit through a request https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-dynamodb-increases-the-number-of-global-secondary-indexes-and-projected-index-attributes-you-can-create-per-table/
2. `GSI` will cost you additional money as you will need to assign Provisioned Throughput to it.
3. `GSI` is eventually consistent, meaning that DynamoDB does not guarantee that the moment data associated to the table's hash key is written into DB, the data's `GSI` hash key immediately becomes available for querying. DynamoDB doc states that this is usually immediate, but can be the case that it could take up to seconds for the `GSI` hash key to become available.
4. You cannot perform `GetItem` on a `GSI` to obtain an item based on its `Hash Key` / `Hash Key` + `Range Key`. You are limited to use `Query` which returns a `List`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm using RFC 4122 UUIDs for the ID attribute, so your comment about solution #1 being a misuse of a range key is probably fair. However, this drawback is only conceptual, while the drawbacks of using a GSI are quite tangible. This definitely gives me something to think about, though.

Comment: I believe you can change GSI on the fly now.

Comment: If you use a simple primary key for the table, can you still query it? I thought that you could only scan tables with simple primary keys (hash without a range).

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715002/optional-secondary-indexes-in-dynamodb/21957750#21957750) may be of some use, but you're right about the two ways that you could accomplish it.

Assuming that you use `id` as your hash key, then in order to retrieve an item using only a timestamp, you'll need a global secondary index.  You can still make `timestamp` your the range key, which will be useful in that DynamoDB will use it to sort the results your queries by `id`.

The main drawback of using a global secondary index is that you'll need additional provisioned throughput on the table.

Comment: Do you mean that even if I have hash+range key combination, if i want to query only range key, i still need to define range key as global secondary index?

Comment: @batmaci - Yes, any time you want to perform a query in DynamoDB you'll need to specify the hash key, whether that's the table's main hash key or an index's hash key. Think of DynamoDB as a hash table - if you don't have they key, then you have to scan through the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar interest and was considering creating a secondary index on a portion of the timestamp (e.g., day or hour) as the HASH and the Id as the RANGE to allow for a query against a particular time slice, but this would force all records within a time slice to be in the same partition for the index.

For being able to query recent data vs. historical data, Amazon recommends a multi-table design approach - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html.